# API Integration using MULE- AnyPoint Studio and RAML (RESTful API Modeling Language)

Tags: web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, mule, raml

i am new to mule-AnyPoint Studio. 
 Is it essential to use RAML for api integration using mule- AnyPoint Studio in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not essential.

While exposing an API, is simply making your app able to be called as a service from a remote application, you could just put your favourite endpoints (http, ftp, file, etc).

Now, if you want to create a REST API, you will be exposing HTTP in a way of representing your resources and methods.

But, why to do all that stuff manually, and then need to document it, and validate, and if you change something, need to touch all the places where you manually worked, if you could write a RAML file (design API-First) and then use APIKit+Mule to represent the corresponding flows for that API?

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to use RAML for API integration in mule. Also the type of file you use is generally based on which webservice you are consuming (SOAP/REST).It's better to use the RAML definitions to design the API first.